# Service fabric - Manual Actor Deactivation for debug/testing purposes

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm working on a Service Fabric project using ReliableActors with a state. I save and delete things in the state of the actor, and have some re-activation logic that I want to test.

Is there a way to manually deactivate or garbage collect an actor? I would optimally have a test loading data into the actor, deactivating it, and then run some function to ensure that the actor still opperates as intended.

Answer (score 3):

You can [adjust](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-lifecycle/) the time an actor is considered as idle to force more frequent garbage collection. Code from the documentation:

```
ActorRuntime.RegisterActorAsync<MyActor>((context, actorType) =>
        new ActorService(context, actorType,
                settings:
                    new ActorServiceSettings()
                    {
                        ActorGarbageCollectionSettings =
                            new ActorGarbageCollectionSettings(idleTimeoutInSeconds: 20, scanIntervalInSeconds:20)
                    }))
        .GetAwaiter()
        .GetResult();
```

As you can see, there are two parameters: idleTimeoutInSeconds — after that time an actor that is doing nothing could be considered for deactivation; scanIntervalInSeconds — time interval in which service fabric will check actors on their inactivity.

Comment: idleTimeoutInSeconds must be equal to or greater than scanIntervalInSeconds

Answer (score 1):

If you mean delete when you say "deactivate", you can use the following:

```
await myActorServiceProxy.DeleteActorAsync(actorToDelete, cancellationToken)
```

> An actor is activated the first time a call is made to any of its methods. An actor is deactivated (garbage collected by the Actors runtime) if it is not used for a configurable period of time. An actor and its state can also be deleted manually at any time.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-lifecycle.md

Comment: I am aware of this, however this deletes the state of the actor as well, and is not what i need.

Comment: You can still use the "DeleteActorAsync" method. One way that comes in mind, is to inject the State Manager as part of your test. See the new functionality in SDK 2.2 (Actor Dependency Injection). public class MockStateManager : IActorStateManager

Comment: Not as clean as I'd like, but I'll look into it and see if this can solve my problem. Thanks!